# XSLT - Use of copy-of seems to be ignoring "if" statment in template

Tags: xml, xslt

I've posted another query earlier today regarding including tags that apply to different templates and I received some responses that helped me get the output I wanted. Now, I have one more small detail to resolve.  My XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
    <account>
        <name>accountA</name>
    </account>
    <period>
        <type>priormonth</type>
        <balance>0.0000</balance>
    </period>
    <period>
        <type>currentmonth</type>
        <balance>20.0000</balance>
    </period>
    <account>
        <name>accountB</name>
    </account>
    <period>
        <type>priormonth</type>
        <balance>30.0000</balance>
    </period>
    <period>
        <type>currentmonth</type>
        <balance>0.0000</balance>
    </period>
</root>
```

My XSLT looks like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="account"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="account">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="name" />
        <perioddata>
            <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::period[position()&lt;=2]" />
        </perioddata>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="period">
    <period>
    <type> <xsl:value-of select="type"/> </type>
    <balance>
    <xsl:if test="balance != 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="balance"/>
    </xsl:if>
    </balance>
    </period>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is yielding output as follows:

```
<account>
  <name>accountA</name>
  <perioddata>
      <period>
          <type>priormonth</type>
          <balance>0.0000</balance>
      </period>
      <period>
          <type>currentmonth</type>
          <balance>20.0000</balance>
      </period>
   </perioddata>
</account>
<account>
  <name>accountB</name>
  <perioddata>
      <period>
          <type>priormonth</type>
          <balance>30.0000</balance>
      </period>
      <period>
          <type>currentmonth</type>
          <balance>0.0000</balance>
      </period>
   </perioddata>
</account>
```

This output is fine except that I want my lines with:

```
<balance>0.0000</balance>
```

to appear as:

```
<balance/>
```

Apologies for any typos above...I was mainly just typing rather than cut/paste. I was reading that "copy-of" can be the same as "value-of" and produce text output which could explain why the "if" clause isn't recognizing the zero value.  I tried to do:

```
<xsl:if test="number(balance) != 0">
```

but still didn't get the results I want.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing

```
<xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::period[position()&lt;=2]" />
```

to

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::period[position()&lt;=2]" />
```

Your "period" template is not being used as the nodes are consumed by the "root" template.

Comment: Fantastic!  That worked...thanks.  Don't know why I didn't try that earlier because I did play around with various apply-templates options.  You made my Friday!

Comment: I made a minor change to my answer.  It's actually the "root" template that's consuming the "period" nodes as a side-effect, since you didn't do anything with them in the "root" template.  This is why you have to do apply-templates instead of copy-of.  Your copy-of was just copying the nodes verbatim, not invoking your template.